# If $f(x)=x^7+x^5+x^3+x$, show that $f(x)=1$ has a unique solution. How do I prove this?

Tags: calculus, functions

What I did was

- use the intermediate value theorem for the existence of a solution
- used the first derivative to show that $f(x)$ is increasing and thus $f(x)=1$ has a unique solution

Is that correct?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is correct, $f'(x)>0$ implies that $f$ strictly increase, $lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, $lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ use the IVT to show the existence of an unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that "solution" means real solution.

$f(x)=x^7+x^5+x^3+x-1$ has at least one real solution because it is of odd degre. If $f(x)$  had two or more solutions then $f(x)$ should present at least an extremum. But it is not the case because the derivative$$f'(x)= 7x^6+5x^4+3x^2+1$$ obviously is never equal to zero.

Comment: your f(x) is wrong, it shouldnt include a ''-1''

Comment: @SwantE-:  solutions of $g(x)=x^7+x^5+x^3+x-1=0$ are solutions to $f(x)=1$

Comment: So this question is asking whether there is only one number that outputs to 1?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, but he didnt say g(x), and f(x) was already specified to be x^7+x^5+x^3+x. He also didnt say g(x)=0, he just said f(x). Your statement is wrong in 2 ways